# macOS Docker ssh failed

Tags: docker, macos, ssh

I want to use ssh to access the docker container on my Mac (docker is also installed on the Mac).

I don't know how to solve this problem, if you have a way, I will sincerely appreciate it.

```
ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.2 port 9999: Operation timed out
```

I have a docker image of ubuntu1804, I tried it in the following way：

```
1. docker run -itd -p 192.168.31.151:9999:22 slamcabbage/221212_ubuntu1804 /bin/bash
```

```
2. docker exec -it 95a3f4c876b00 /bin/bash
```

After entering the container, i tried below：

```
apt-get update
apt-get install passwd openssl openssh-server openssh-client
passwd
echo "Port 22" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo "PasswordAuthentication yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

finally

```
service ssh restart
```

After that, I try to ssh in macos terminal：

```
ssh root@172.17.0.2 -p9999                           
ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.2 port 9999: Operation timed out
```

Comment: Hello, I think ssh is necessary for me, because the next thing I want to do is related to ROS multi-machine network connection

Comment: I suspect the `docker run -p IPADDR:...` suboption may not work well on MacOS, for reasons similar to the problems with host networking.  Does deleting that part of the option, and connecting to `localhost` and not some other IP address, work better?